Listview make container disappear
I am doing the homepage of an app in flutter but when I try to wrap the container in a ListView it disappears... I think it's affected because the container it's wrapped in a Column?
Here is the code for homepage
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'post_detail.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flashy_tab_bar2/flashy_tab_bar2.dart';
import 'Influencerprofile.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> tabItems = [
    Center(child: Text("0")),
    Center(child: Text("1")),
    Center(child: Text("2")),
    Center(child: Text("3")),
    Center(child: Text("4"))
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          'INFLUFIT.CLUB',
          style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
     
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, children: [
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search influencer",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                    )))
          ])),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Text(
                'Location',
                style: TextStyle(),
              )),
          PostDetail(),
        ]),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FlashyTabBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showElevation: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: [
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Feed'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text('Favourites'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('Add'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
            ),
            title: Text('Alerts'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('My profile'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

And here is the code for PostDetail() that I try to wrap in a ListView in the homepage and duplicate it 5 times
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Influencerprofile.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class PostDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PostDetailState createState() => PostDetailState();
}

class PostDetailState extends State<PostDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/avatar.png',
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Influencerprofile()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'User Name',
                          // widget.UserName,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('@username'
                              // widget.Post,
                              ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                              child: Image.asset('assets/verified.png'))
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          height: 75,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                            shadows: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                blurRadius: 10,
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: const Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Subscribers',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Text('356'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                VerticalDivider(
                                  indent: 8,
                                  endIndent: 8,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Programs',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Text('8'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                VerticalDivider(
                                  indent: 8,
                                  endIndent: 8,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Ratings',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Text('5.0'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ])),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              "SUBSCRIBE",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(60)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

What I should add for the PostDetail() to not disappear anymore in the homepage?

Column tries to expands in vertical axis, and so does the ListView, hence you need to constrain the height of ListView.
Use either Expanded or Flexible if you want to allow ListView to take up entire left space in Column.
Try this where you have put PostDetail() in the homepage column (See last paragraph of this answer to know why I used ListView.builder instead of ListView):
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tabItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostDetail(),
          ),
        ),

itemCount is the number of times you want to display the container. You can specify it as any integer like 5,6,7... or like I did that is length of your tabItems list.
We can do the same task with the help of ListView instead of ListView.builder but when we have numerous items(for ex: 10000) then it is inefficient to create these items with ListView because it loads all the list items at once but ListView.builder make this task quicker by creating layouts for  items visible on the screen with the help of itemBuilder & lazily build other layouts/containers as the user scrolls.
The above method will duplicate the PostDetail() as many times as you specify
To display different users
create a model for Post and specify whatever a post needs (Example given below):
class Post {
  final String userName;
  final String imagePath;
  final String subscriberCount;

  Post({
    required this.userName,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.subscriberCount,
  });
}

Create a List of type Post and add however many user details you want:
final List<Post> myPosts = [
Post(
  userName: 'Lili',
  imagePath: '<Your Path>',
  subscriberCount: '354',
),
Post(
  userName: 'New User',
  imagePath: '<Your Path>',
  subscriberCount: '290',
),]

Create constructors in PostDetail():
class PostDetail extends StatefulWidget {
    final String myUsername;
    final String myImagePath;
    final String mySubsCount;

    PostDetail({super.key, required this.myUsername, required this.myImagePath, required this.mySubsCount})

  @override
  PostDetailState createState() => PostDetailState();
}

Use the above constructors instead of static texts in your PostDetail():
instead of Text('User Name') use Text(myUsername)
instead of Text('356') use Text(mySubsCount) and so on..
Modify the ListView.Builder as follows:
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: myPosts.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final Post post = myPosts[index] //to access each element of myPosts list

              return PostDetails(
                myUsername = post.username,
                myImagePath = post.imagePath,
                mySubsCount = post.subscriberCount,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),

Hope this helps.

Q: It duplicates the same user profile x5 times , if I want to be different users I should change something in post detail , not?

@Lili I have modified the answer according to this, you can try that
